# Low accuracy for text classification using LSTM model

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm, text-classification

I am trying to train an LSTM model for fake news detection using title and text features of the dataset. Below is the code of my model:

```
    vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1 #gives me a value of 12
    embedding_dim = 50
    maxlen = 50
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen))
    model.add(layers.LSTM(128,activation = "relu"))
    model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation = 'softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer = opt,
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    model_train = model.fit(X_train_cnn, y_train2,
                epochs = 15,
                verbose = True,
                validation_data=(X_test_cnn, y_test2),
                batch_size = 32)
```

The accuracy for both train and validation data is around 47%

```
Epoch 15/15
30081/30081 [==============================] - 60s 2ms/step - loss: 7.9900 - accuracy: 0.4789 - val_loss: 8.0780 - val_accuracy: 0.4732
```

confusion matrix:

```
array([[   0, 7806],
       [   0, 7011]], dtype=int64)
```

classification report:

```
precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.00      0.00      0.00      7806
           1       0.47      1.00      0.64      7011

    accuracy                           0.47     14817
```

I have tried different combinations of epochs, batch_size, 2 LSTM layers with different units, but no luck. Please help me on this.

Comment: your it's a binary classification problem if u use softmax the last dimension must be equal to the number of class (2 in your case and not 1). if u are interested in some example let me know

Comment: If I set the last layer as you mentioned with 2: model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation = 'sigmoid')) I get the following error when I train the model: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_7 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: I didn't say you Dense(2, activation = 'sigmoid')... I say u Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'). I suppose also you have numerical encoded targets so u need sparse_categorical_crossentropy as loss

Comment: I ll change the loss and the activation function and try running now

Comment: Does the changing activation function and loss, effect the accuracy significantly?

Comment: the accuracy increased to 52% but the still getting zero for precision, recall, F1 score for target class: 1

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem as 0 precision and recall. Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: @MrRaghav No, how about you?